# wordpress htaccess overrides laravel

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

I have been installed wordpress (domain http://example.com) in public_html and I installed laravel in public_html/laravel/ directory, when I try to access example.com/laravel I get laravel logo that means it works fine but when I try to access example.com/laravel/test I get wordpress 404, I noticed that when i remove .htaccess in root (public_html) folder laravel works fine and returns some view

this is my wordpress htaccess ...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel/ #added for Laravel routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Here, were simply stating that, in order to route to Wordpress, the following three considitions must be met:

- The request string/URI must not begin with "/laravel/"
- The request does not link to a file
- The request does not link to a directory

Answer (score 0):

Solved !
Added "/laravel/" in Laravel .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /laravel/index.php [L]
```